# Stetho showing two columns with same name

Tags: android, sqlite, stetho

Hello I am using Stetho debugging platform for my application.
I have added Stetho in my gradle as follows

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.2.0'
```

}

and initialized it into onCreate method as follows

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this);
    findElementsByIds();
    addDataIntoDBs();
    initData();
}
```

I have created Category table (as cat_id and cat_name columns) for demo and added some entries into it, please see 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEj3V.png) screenshot.

Can anyone tell why it is showing two columns with same name as in the image

code which I have done for table creation

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private static String DATABASE_NAME = "citizan.db";
private static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static DBHelper dbHelperInstance = null;
private static SQLiteDatabase dbInstance= null;

public static String CATEGORY_TABLE = "category";
public static String CAT_ID = "cat_id";
public static String CAT_NAME = "cat_name";
private String CREATE_CATEGORY_TABLE = "create table "+CATEGORY_TABLE + "("+CAT_ID+" Integer primary key autoincrement, " +CAT_NAME+ " text"+")";
private String DROP_CATEGORY_TABLE = "drop table if exists "+CATEGORY_TABLE;

private DBHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, AppConstants.DATABASE_NAME, null,AppConstants.DATABASE_VERSION);

}

public static  synchronized  DBHelper getInstance(Context context) {
    if(dbHelperInstance == null)
    {
        dbHelperInstance = new DBHelper(context);
    }
    return dbHelperInstance;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CATEGORY_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
     db.execSQL(DROP_CATEGORY_TABLE);
     onCreate(db);
}

public static  void openConnection()
{
    if(dbInstance == null)
    {
        dbInstance = dbHelperInstance.getWritableDatabase();
    }
}

public void addCategories(String[] catArray)  {
   openConnection();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    for (int i=0;i<catArray.length;i++)
    {
        values.put(CAT_NAME, catArray[i]);
        dbInstance.insert(CATEGORY_TABLE,null,values);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Does any one know this?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. I think that is just how it works

Comment: did you figure out why?

Comment: I have this same issue. I see two of my primary key columns in the Chrome web inspector like the screen shot above. 

I verified there weren't any duplicate columns by running this query in the web inspector:
`PRAGMA table_info(MyTableName)`

Comment: Issue is opened in GitHub repo: https://github.com/facebook/stetho/issues/598